# JavaScript closures in for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

As explained here http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62/ code below outputs result just for "5x5" forgetting about anything before that.

```
for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
for (y = 1; y <= 5; y++) {

    var cords = x+"x"+y;
    var el = document.getElementById(cords);
    el.addEventListener("click", function (e) { B_modeWindow('1', cords); });

}
}
```

As far I have the informations (blog link provided above) can't figure out how to alter showed code to fix it.

**How to walk around this code with JavaScript closure in my for-loop?**

*edit: I dont get it. varibles are defined in good way. Test:*

```
for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
for (y = 1; y <= 5; y++) {

    var cords = x+"x"+y;
    alert(cords);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function with anything you need to be closed as an argument. In this case, that's `cords`.

```
for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
    for (y = 1; y <= 5; y++) {
        var cords = x + "x" + y;
        var el = document.getElementById(cords);

        (function(cords) {
            el.addEventListener("click", function (e) { B_modeWindow('1', cords); });
        })(cords);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1656447 - if this doesn't work, then you must have something else you haven't shown that is also causing a problem because this example solves the `for` loop issue with the `cords` variable.

Comment: It should be in every JavaScript newbie book

Answer (score 1):

Minitech was close, but you have to move the closed variables INSIDE the function:

```
for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
    for (y = 1; y <= 5; y++) {
        (function() {
            var cords = x + "x" + y;
            var el = document.getElementById(cords);
            el.addEventListener("click", function (e) { B_modeWindow('1', cords); });
        })();
    }
}
```

Comment: minitech's answer should work just as well.  They close over the `cords` variable which solves the problem.

Comment: But he's not closing over `el`, which is also being used in the function.

Comment: `el` is used ONLY in the actual `for` loop at the time of execution of the `for` loop.  It is not used in the event handler that runs later so it does not need to be closed over.  `coords` is used in the event handler callback itself (e.g. referenced later at the time the event occurs) so it has to be closed over.

Comment: Good point (it's so easy to get lost in the mazes of closures, and I even have many years of Lisp experience). I wonder why the OP said it didn't work.

Comment: This, gentles, is some crazy stuff. Who invented this language?

Comment: It's what you get when you take some of the good ideas from Lisp (objects and closures) but not others (macros). Lisp macros allow you to create syntactic sugar for common idioms to hide the complexity and reduce errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that js variables have function scope, so the cords variable gets rewritten as you go through the loop. Thus all listener functions point to the same variable which ends up with the final value. One solution to this is to create another function that takes el and cords as arguments and adds a cords-based listener to el. Then call this function from your inner loop rather than adding the listener there directly.

Comment: Is that what minitech proposed?

Comment: @user1656447 no, it's kinda the opposite.