# For loop iterator gets incremented before mongoose find is executed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In the below code when i run FOR loop from 0 to 1, since i have added a console log in the beginning of FOR loop, Console prints 0,1 and then executes the mongoose find statement.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < req.body.seatNo.length; i++) {
     console.log(i);
     var pname = req.body.name[i];
     //console.log(pname);
     var page = req.body.age[i]
     //console.log(page);
     busModel.findOne({
         $and: [{
             "ticket.seatNumber": req.body.seatNo[i]
      }, {
             "dateOfJourney": dataG
      }, {
             "ticket.reserved": false
      }]
     }, function (err, doc) {
         duplicateBookCheck.push(i);
         if (doc) {
             console.log("inside doc")
             doc.save(function (err) {
                 if (err) {
                     console.log('save error');
                 } else {
                     //hidden
                 }
             })
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Yes, works as intended. The queries are async. That's why you provide a callback to handle their results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - how to work with the iterator in a for loop with callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377971/javascript-how-to-work-with-the-iterator-in-a-for-loop-with-callbacks)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closures in for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343177/javascript-closures-in-for-loop)